# why do my averages not print out the way they're supposed to?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, number-formatting, drjava

I have to make a program that prints out the average score for each competitor in a gymnastic competition. i have to sort the elements in the arrays, and then drop the lowest and highest scores for each array. i think i have that part figured out (correct me if i'm wrong!), but my averages print out as 4.6900, 0.0000, and 0.9000 when they're supposed to be 5.8625, 0.0000, and 1.0000. this is what my code looks like:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class EZD_gymnastics
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    double comp1[] = {8.7, 6.5, 0.1, 3.2, 5.7, 9.9, 8.3, 6.5, 6.5, 1.5};
    double comp2[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    double comp3[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
    fmt.setMinimumFractionDigits(4);

    Arrays.sort(comp1);

    double sum = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    double sum3 = 0;
    double mean = 0;
    double mean2 = 0;
    double mean3 = 0;

    for(int a = 1; a < 9; a++)
    {
      sum =  sum + comp1[a];
      mean = sum / comp1.length;
    }

    String s = fmt.format(mean);
    System.out.println("For Competitor #1, the average is " + s + ".");

    for(int b = 1; b < 9; b++)
    {
      sum2 =  sum2 + comp2[b];
      mean2 = sum2 / comp2.length;
    }

    String t = fmt.format(mean2);
    System.out.println("For Competitor #2, the average is " + t + ".");


    for(int c = 1; c <9; c++)
    {
      sum3 =  sum3 + comp3[c];
      mean3 = sum3 / comp3.length;
    }

    String u = fmt.format(mean3);
    System.out.println("For Competitor #3, the average is " + u + ".");
  }
}
```

Comment: In Java arrays are indexed from `0`

Comment: this is not duplicate.

Comment: @bugjuice Check this line: `mean = sum / comp1.length;`. You excluded your MIN and MAX when calculate SUM but you still divide the SUM to total number, it should be `sum / (comp1.length - 2)`

Comment: To add on @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn, call `sort` method on other arrays too.